# How to detach an EBS volume from an EC2 (which is under ASG) before it is being scaled down

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, autoscaling, amazon-ebs

I have multiple Non-Production servers where each have 900GB EBS Volume attached. And currently there is a practice of taking snapshot of these instances every day. I want to detach this volume when ASG scales down and reattach it to them when it scales up thus reducing the size of snapshot. The 900GB volume is the Non-Prod DB Volume so I plan to schedule a weekly snapshot of it separately.

NOTE: Each Non-Production ASG will have only one EC2 spot instance max and the scaling up & down is done via scaling policies.

I am trying to setup Event Bridge notification, triggering a Lambda function whenever ASG performs an action. I want to know if there are any other AWS provided service for this or any better way to do this.

Comment: **Side-note:** If possible, it would be good to re-think your architecture. For example, using Amazon EFS for shared storage amongst the EC2 instances instead of using Amazon EBS. Or, it is now possible to mount an Amazon EBS volume on multiple Amazon EC2 instances simultaneously. Rather than trying to build a complex solution to your current architecture, it might involve less effort to move to a simpler shared-storage architecture.

Comment: Hi @John, The DB needs a block store so I can't use EFS, for EBS multi attach, that's something that is limited by app legacy architecture. Also, trying to reduce single point of failure even though it is non-production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default an EBS volume gets detached than the ec2 instance is removed. And for mounting it you can run a script in the user data.

```
/var/awslogs/bin/aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id `your-ebs-volume-id` --instance-id `your-instance-id` --device /dev/xvdk
```

Comment: Is there a way to safely unmount the EBS before the instance is terminated or is the default actions of EC2 already fine ?

Comment: The standard behavior for ebs is to be unmounted with termination of instance. As I understand this is not the root ebs. You can set the root ebs to be deleted on termination.

Comment: Thanks @Erik. Is the unmounting safe and will not impact the data stored ?

Comment: Yes. I have had no issues with it :)